# How to use eloquent to compare a column with a related table column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's say you have search result page that can display cars by a number of criteria, including year released.

When the user doesn't specify a year, I want to pull all cars ("year_models") from the latest available year in each brand. Eg, you would see 2019 Chevys, but 2009 Pontiacs.  In each brand table, I have a "latest_year" column that can be used for this.

Relationships:

- brands (eg, Chevrolet, Ford, etc..)
- --brand_models (Corvette, Silverado,etc.)
- ----year_models (eg, 2019 Corvette)

Each brand has many brand_models. Each brand model has many year_models.

How do I perform this query? Here is my code so far:

```
$year = $request['year'];

$yearModels = YearModel::with([
    'brandModel',
    'brandModel.brand',
])
->when(!$year, function ($q) {
    $q->whereHas('brandModel.brand', function ($q) use ($year) {
        $q->where('latest_year', $YEARMODEL_YEAR?? );
    });
})
...
```

I also tried a "wherecolumn" query but I don't think I can query the brand relationship that way.

Comment: Could you please show the table structure and data of it. (take a screenshot)

Comment: @sachinkumar Not sure what you mean by screenshot of the data. I added a sentence describing the relationships, which are all working fine. If there is something more specific that would help, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking about doing something like

```
$query = YearModel::with([
                'brandModel',
                'brandModel.brand',
            ]
        );
if (!$year) {
    $query = $query->whereRaw('column_one', 'column_2');
}

$result = $query->get();
```

This [thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/problem-for-comparing-two-fields-with-a-where?page=1#reply=143923) may help you. You may need to change the query based on your table structure.

Example in tinker

```
>>> App\models\Student::whereRaw('standard_id', 'section_id')->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3225
     all: [
       App\models\Student {#3226
         id: 1,
         first_name: "Farhan",
         last_name: "Pasha",
         gender: "m",
         date_of_birth: "2001-02-02",
         roll_number: 1,
         standard_id: 1,
         section_id: 1,
         school_id: 1,
         photo: "",
         created_at: "2019-10-07 07:36:21",
         updated_at: "2019-10-10 10:42:37",
       },
       App\models\Student {#3213
         id: 2,
         first_name: "Mohameed",
         last_name: "Khalil",
         gender: "m",
         date_of_birth: "2013-05-27",
         roll_number: 2,
         standard_id: 1,
         section_id: 1,
         user_id: 1,
         school_id: 1,
         photo: "",
         created_at: "2019-10-14 07:15:10",
         updated_at: "2019-10-14 07:15:10",
       },
     ],
   }
>>>
```

Comment: I did try something like that via the `wherecolumn` method. But for that to work, "column_two" would need to be in a different table, and in a relation to column_one. Eg, something like `$query->whereRaw('release_year', $yearmodel->brandModel->brand->latest_year );`  (which obviously doesn't work. Just illustrating what I think needs to happen)

Comment: @sersun see, I just tried the same thing in tinker for student having same `standard_id` and `section_id` and I am getting correct result.

Comment: Your recommendation only works for comparing two columns in the same table. I need to compare a column in the the queried table (year_models) to `latest_year`  column in a related row of table `brands`. It has to be the brand that belongs to the year_model.

Comment: @sersun In that case you can either use raw sub query in your where condition or use join.

Answer (score 0):

Think how you would write this query with plain SQL, probably it should be something like this:

```
SELECT b.brand, bm.model, ym.year from brands b
left join brand_models bm on b.id = bm.brand_id
left join year_models ym on ym.model_id = bm.model_id
group by b.brand, bm.model, ym.year having ym.year = max(ym.year)
```

Then try to convert this to eloquent.

```
$brands = Brands::with(["brandModel", "brandModel.yearModel")
    ->groupBy("id, brandModel.id, brandModel.yearModel.id");

if(!isset($year)){
    $brands = $brands->having("brand.yearModel.year", "=", \DB::raw("max(brandModel.yearModel.year)"));
} else {
    $brands = $brands->having("brand.yearModel.year", "=", $year);
}

$results = $brands->get();
```